# TensorBoard can not read summaries on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-storage, tensorboard

When I used TensorBoard with TensorFlow v0.9.0, TensorFlow can read summaries on Google Cloud Storage as `tensorboard --logdir=gs://...`.

However, TensorBoard with TensorFlow v0.11.0 can not read it.
Did something change from v0.9.0 to v0.11.0?

The error message is as follow.

`W tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/google_auth_provider.cc:151] All attempts to get a Google authentication bearer token failed, returning an empty token. Retrieving token from files failed with "Unavailable: libcurl failed with error code 23: Failed writing body (101 != 188)". Retrieving token from GCE failed with "Unavailable: Unexpected response code 0".`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Could you please try running `gcloud auth application-default login` ? After that TensorBoard should be able to get the required credentials for accessing GCS.

The reason is that TensorBoard now uses the Application Default Credentials, see  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials

Comment: Running `gcloud auth application-default login` did not solve the error message for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi! Sorry about the delay. Could you try this with TF 1.0 or TF 1.0.1 and see if the error is still there? 

TensorFlow now statically links its version of libcurl instead of dynamically using the version of libcurl installed in the system, which could have some incompatibilities with the TensorFlow code. Also, some changes were made in the recent couple months with regard to how the write buffer is handled in the libcurl integration.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer please make sure to install `fsspec` and `gcsfs` packages.

```
pip install fsspec gcsfs
```

Comment: Thank you. Couldn't get anything to work at all without this.